# Navigation View Always Visible in Android

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I want to open navigation view with bottom app bar click. But navigation view always visible .

My layout xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Light"
    >


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="132dp"
        android:background="@drawable/login_bg2_gradient"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="44dp"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="91dp"
                android:layout_height="23dp"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:text="SAMET DAĞ"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView7"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView5" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
                android:text="8 Şubat 2019 11:05"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_width="69dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:text="MOSTA"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.972"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView8"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu_manage" />


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>


        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:menu="@menu/profile_side_menu" />

        <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:id="@+id/coordinatorlayout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="89dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/nav_view"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.938">

            <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
                android:id="@+id/bottombar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:backgroundTint="#949494"
                app:buttonGravity="bottom|top"
                app:fabAlignmentMode="center"
                app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_menu_black_24dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="606dp"

                />

            <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/bottom_float_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/shift_change"
                android:src="@drawable/shift_change"
                app:backgroundTint="@android:color/darker_gray"
                app:fabCustomSize="50dp"
                app:layout_anchor="@+id/bottombar"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottombar"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bottombar" />

        </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

My java code :

```
package com.stawiz;

import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import android.system.Os;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
import com.mxn.soul.flowingdrawer_core.ElasticDrawer;
import com.mxn.soul.flowingdrawer_core.FlowingDrawer;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainMenu extends AppCompatActivity {

    FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton;
    BottomAppBar bottomAppBar;

    CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout;

    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;

    Button btnLogOut,btnEditProfile;

    NavigationView navigationView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_menu);

        floatingActionButton = findViewById(R.id.bottom_float_button);

        bottomAppBar = findViewById(R.id.bottombar);

        coordinatorLayout=findViewById(R.id.coordinatorlayout);

        drawerLayout=findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        navigationView  = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);


        setSupportActionBar(bottomAppBar);

       bottomAppBar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() { // It working when profile button pressed.
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

                Log.e("asdas","--asdasd");



                if(drawerLayout.isDrawerVisible(Gravity.RIGHT)){
                    Log.e("right","right");
                }
                if(drawerLayout.isDrawerVisible(Gravity.LEFT)){
                    Log.e("LEFT","LEFT");
                }
                if(drawerLayout.isDrawerVisible(GravityCompat.START)){
                    Log.e("START","START");
                }
                if(drawerLayout.isDrawerVisible(GravityCompat.END)){
                    Log.e("END","END");
                }


                return true;
            }
        });

     bottomAppBar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {//It working when menu button pressed.
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {

             BottomNavigationDrawer bottomNavigationDrawer = new BottomNavigationDrawer();

             bottomNavigationDrawer.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),bottomNavigationDrawer.getTag());
         }
     });



    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.bottom_app_bar_menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

      /*  switch (item.getItemId()){

            case

        }*/


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 1) {
            finish();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }


    }


}
```

I want to show navigation view with  `bottomAppBar.setOnMenuItemClickListener`. App goes there but navigation view always showing. I just want to show navigation view with this click listener. How can i do that ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's navigation_view in Activity and nav_view in XML, both are different?

Comment: You're right . I changed that. But seems it's not the issue. Still navigation view appearing always.

Answer (score 0):

You are opening it when you start activity. Please remove the line in `onCreate` method

```
drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
```

and change

```
android:layout_gravity="end"
```

to

```
android:layout_gravity="start"
```

Comment: Sir I'm sorry i didn't mention that I want navigation view RTL. So I used end or right. I didn't use framelayout . Could it be problem for that ?

Comment: It really worked. I put all contents except navigation view into Framelayout then navigation after that it worked like what i expected. Thank you for help.